# User Control on Active Report

Tags: c#, activereports

I know I can draw on Active Reports, but let's leave that as a last resort.

I have a user control where all I do is draw graphics in the OnPaint method (Since that is the only way I can get the graphics to show). I know Active Reports is static, but I would have liked it to paint once. Instead I just get the gray box. Is there a way to accomplish this, or am I stuck converting my stuff to draw directly in Active Reports? I tried suspending the OnPaint method after running the code that draws the graphics, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveReports does support hosting a .net component.   No need to paint directly on AR surface.    It is not an ideal scenario but it should work.   We would need more details to diagnose why your user control is not working.  which section are you placing it in?  is it bound or static graphics?   you should know that AR paints the controls at processing time, it binds the controls then paints them to its own format (RDF) then the viewer only understands that format (think of it like a sheet of paper).    This means that you need to place your control on the report and have it render it, rather than trying to render it in the viewer.

Anyway, more details about your control and the report you're using it in would help.   please contact us at activereports.support@grapecity.com and we'll do our best to help.

thanks
http://activereports.grapecity.com

Comment: Ok, I emailed. Thank you, I'll update when I get more info.

Answer (score 0):

After working with GrapeCity I was able to get it working after making these 3 changes (I'm sure it's just the last that matters):

1. Switched to inherit from Control instead of UserControl
2. Overrode the OnPaint method instead of just subscribing to the Paint event
3. used the PaintEventArg e's e.Graphics instead of this.CreateGraphics()

Then declare it all in the report like so:

```
 private void SectionReport1_ReportStart(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.CustomControl cc;
        MyControl myc = new MyControl();           
        cc = new GrapeCity.ActiveReports.SectionReportModel.CustomControl(myc.GetType());
        cc.Location = new PointF(1f, 1f);
        cc.Size = new SizeF(4f, 4f);            
        this.detail.Controls.Add(cc);
    }
```